# convert ifupdown bridge config to netplan

Tags: netplan

How can I implement "iface br-mgmt:0" in netplan config file
from the ifupdown config file?

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet manual

auto eth0.10
iface eth0.10 inet manual
   vlan-raw-device eth0

auto br-mgmt
iface br-mgmt inet static
bridge_ports eth0.10
address 10.4.4.38
netmask 255.255.252.0
gateway 10.4.4.0

auto br-mgmt:0
iface br-mgmt:0 inet static
    address 10.4.4.11
    netmask 255.255.252.0
```

Comment: Have you looked at http://netplan.io/examples ? Seems like a couple examples look very much like your case.

Answer (score 0):

Netplan does not support interface aliases.  You can assign multiple addresses to a single interface.